# Python Linux Joystick support?

Tags: python, linux, pygame, hid, joystick

How can I use an analog joystick in Python on Linux? I come from a C++ background, where I used joystick.h to read events from /dev/input/js[x]. Is there a python wrapper around this I can use, perhaps? I don't really want to have to use a huge library like pyGame or SDL?

Comment: I don't know if it's the same interface, but this might be what you're looking for. http://sourceforge.net/projects/joy2xev/

Answer (score 3):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/rdb/8864666) worked for me on Ubuntu 15.04 without modification.

Answer (score 2):

There is [evdev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/evdev/0.1.1), It's only for Linux, and it seems to be able to do much more than just handling joystick. I've never tried it, though.

I spent some time looking for a library to *only* read joystick in a cross-platform way, but didn't find any, and I've ended up with pygame (only initializing joystick and event modules) in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Now (2016+) there's  a new sufficiently multiplatform Python module called "inputs" that you can find on [GitHub](https://github.com/zeth/inputs) or install from [Pipy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inputs)

It can read joysticks, controllers, keyboards and mices and seems to offer a good support for all their features, including vibration where available.